# vim-latex does not display compilation errors

Tags: pdftex, vim, vim-latex

I installed vim-latex using Vundle and have been trying to use it to write a LaTeX document. Using `\ll` compiles the document if there are no errors and opens the .pdf in my pdf viewer, exactly was I would like. However, if there is an error, the document does not compile and the errors do not seem to be displayed any where. The quickfix window does not open, and if I open one manually using `:copen`, no errors are displayed. I'm not entirely sure how to proceed as I there does not seem to be anything about this behavior in the tutorials or online.

Comment: Do you have this in your `vimrc` or `init.vim`? `let g:vimtex_log_verbose = 1`